# What does "save as" do exactly in chrome?

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-chrome, web

I have a resume webpage I am working on and it contains a `google` map to show where I have been.

When I open it in my browser and do "save as", I thought that would create the exact copy of the project folder but no. this is what happens
https://i.stack.imgur.com/lC2Jp.jpg (`savedfromChrome` is after and `actualProject` is before)

Maybe the new folder saved from browser is a compressed version but then again, `google map` doesn't seem to work there. So I thought maybe it only saves the html file. Then again in the inner folder, there are `js` files including the ones I had in the `project/js/`.

What are those `vt` files and extra `javascript` files that I didn't have in the original project folder (see the last picture in the album) ? also why doesn't the `google map` work ? when I start the saved html that I got from doing "save as"?

Comment: Can't see your image.

Answer (score 0):

When you save a webpage like that, the browser saves everything to your drive, all resources and HTML that is currently loaded, and it also alters it so that when you view the page locally, URLs translate to the stored files.

What is happening is your saved version of the map isn't able to access some of the dynamic content that it needs in order to run. If you click the Menu button in Chrome, go to More Tools, and then Javascript Console, you will likely see errors on the local version of the page. When an error occurs, the browser stops running that bit of script, thus leaving you with a non-functioning map.

If you want a map like that for local use, you can always take a screenshot of the map and edit it to your needs. You can do this with Alt+Print Screen on most systems. On Windows, this will save the image to your clipboard. You can then use MS Paint (or your favorite editor) and paste the image in for editing and saving.

Comment: it's an interactive map where you can zoom in and move. why can't the saved version of the map access the dynamic content? also what are those vt files(vt(1), vt(2) etc)?